# Exemplo de JpaRepository ou PagingAndSortingRepository em um dataTable do primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces, spring-data

Estou aprendendo um pouco de spring boot e fiz uma aplicação de cadastros de usuario / cliente, e gostaria de colocar no meu dataTable do primefaces uma paginação lazy. Alguém teria algum exemplo simples de uma tela com estas 2 tecnologias funcionando para eu poder entender e aprender.

Desde já agradeço a todos.

O que estou utilizando no meu projeto em maven

jsf-spring-boot-starter

primefaces-spring-boot-starter

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

spring-boot-starter-web

spring-boot-devtools

postgresql